# using regular exp. in python

Tags: python, regex

if i am entering email address of the form username@companyname.com and i just wanna search '@' then why is this code isn't working.
``'

```
emailAddress=raw_input()
pat = '@'
match = re.match(pat2,emailAddress)
print match.group()
```

```﻿

Comment: If your code really is the one shown above, you are using 'pat2' instead of pat.

Comment: If you just want to check if `@` is in `emailAddress` just do `'@' in emailAddress`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `pat`/`pat2` issue is just a typo, you want to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`. `search` searches the whole string for a match while `match` only searches for matches beginning at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Actual working e-mails may not be detected by the regexes like '[\w]+@[\w]+\.[w]+', so you'll be safer using some validation server or, better yet, sending confirmation email. Also your code is just checking if there is '@' or not, which will return True for eg 'a@a@a@a' which is obviously not somewhere you can send mail.